# intellij unresolved symbol for go lang project

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I am using go sdk 1.2.1 linux/386 in intellij 14.0.3. However, when I open a golang project many function and variable are unresolved. I do not what is wrong with intellij. Anything that I can do to make the unresolved symbol solved. I have met the problems before. but I do not know to to solve it. Anyone have met the same problem before? Please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I have no information about which plugin version you are using I'm going to assume that you have 0.9.15.3 release.

The fastest way to fix it would be to use one of the early releases for 1.0.0, available here: [github releases page for go plugin for intellij idea](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/releases)

The plugin is currently under a major refactoring and we've started releasing preview builds for it. While the alpha name might be scary, I'm using it daily at work and it's very stable but not everything is up on par with the quality we want it to have.

If you have any further questions, either ask here or browse in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20milestone%3A1.0.0)

Also, there's a small community on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin) and you may get answers from there as well.

Comment: I have same problem with PyCharm 2016.2.3 Community Edition, Go Plugin 0.12.1799, Go 1.7, Windows 10

Comment: Please open an issue on the bug tracker, it's impossible to tell what's the problem (or solution) without a having more details. Thanks.